# Converting Complex Tensors to JS Arrays

Tags: tensorflow.js

When converting complex tensors to JS arrays using data() or dataSync() functions, the returned array is twice the size of the original tensor, containing real and imaginary parts as two different values. I'm expecting a complex number array.

```js
async function convertToArray(){
    r = tf.tensor([1,2,3])
    i = tf.tensor([4,5,6])
    
    c = tf.complex(r,i)
    arr = await c.dataSync()
    console.log(arr)
};

convertToArray();
```

Output is: Float32Array(6) [ 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6 ]
while the expected output is a complex array like this: [ { re: 1, im: 4 }, { re: 2, im: 5 }, { re: 3, im: 6 } ]

If I use, array() or arraySync() functions, I'm getting a "Error: [3] does not match the input size" error.

Comment: Given the example of the question what result do you expect ?

Comment: updated the question. I expect a complex number array like [ { re: 1, im: 4 }, { re: 2, im: 5 }, { re: 3, im: 6 } ]

Comment: It is not possible. But you can write it yourself. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
r = tf.tensor([1,2,3])
i = tf.tensor([4,5,6])

c = tf.complex(r,i)
arr = await c.dataSync()

// convert to an array of object

t = arr.reduce((a, b, i) => i % 2 === 0 ?
    [...a, [b]] :
    [...a.slice(0, a.length - 1), a[a.length - 1].concat(b)], [])
    .map(([a, b]) => ({ re: a, im: b }))
console.log(t)
```

Comment: This works. But, then I need to convert it back to tensor again after a couple of mathjs operations on it.

Comment: You will have to do the inverse operation